# nrf24l01 & Arduino Mega & ESP32S

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp32

I have two modules of nrf24l01 and an Arduino MEGA & ESP32S. Mega is the transmitter and ESP32S is the receiver.

**Issue:**

I'm transmitting a simple message. Receiver is getting `radio.available()` but when printing the message, it's empty. I suspect that it's radio noise or something. I have been trying other solutions and it didn't work, so I reverted back to the extremly basic implementation.

**Actual:**

No actual communication, radio is empty despite having `radio.available()`

**Expected:**

`Hello World` showing up.

**Code - Transmitter:**

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

RF24 radio(7, 8); // CE, CSN
const byte address[6] = "00001";
void setup() {
  radio.begin();
  radio.openWritingPipe(address);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  radio.stopListening();
}
void loop() {
  const char text[] = "Hello World";
  radio.write(&text, sizeof(text));
  delay(1000);
}
```

**Code - Receiver:**

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>
RF24 radio(4, 5); // CE, CSN
const byte address[6] = "00001";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  radio.begin();
  radio.openReadingPipe(0, address);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  radio.startListening();
}
void loop() {
  if (radio.available()) {
    char text[32] = "s";
    radio.read(&text, sizeof(text));
    Serial.println(text);
  }
}
```

The NRF24l01 have the following pins

[image]

Mega connection:

- `GND  => GND`
- `VCC  => 3.3V`
- `CE   => PIN 7`
- `CSN  => PIN 8`
- `SCK  => PIN 52`
- `MOSI => PIN 51`
- `MISO => PIN 50`
- `IRQ - NOT CONNECTED`

[image]

ESP32S connection:

- `GND  => GND`
- `VCC  => 3.3V`
- `CE   => PIN D4`
- `CSN  => PIN D5`
- `SCK  => PIN D18`
- `MOSI => PIN D32`
- `MISO => PIN D19`
- `IRQ - NOT CONNECTED`

[image]

Comment: Try use `radio.read(&text, radio.getPayloadSize());` on your receiver sketch.

Comment: It's also giving empty text and looping extremely fast

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why people are not using IRQ ?

IRQ - NOT CONNECTED

I am currently tracing the origin of this fritzing picture and it appears this turned up in a question on Arduino. https://forum.arduino.cc/t/connecting-2-esp32-wroom-with-nrf24l01-radio-module/1056258

The answer was:
The receiver is not connected properly